# How to get rid of noise when playing multiple sounds with web audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer

I have multiple sounds which should be played one after another or some of them should be played at the same time. I used Web Audio API and made buffers for each sound file and they are played but I hear a noise or kind of bad sound which is not in my audio files.
How could I remove the noise?

Comment: It will be very hard to help you solve this problem if you don't post your code.

Answer (score 0):

The bad sound is probably distortion.  Try reducing the [`gain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode.gain) for the [`GainNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) you are using to control volume.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion reduces that bad sound but it does not solve the problem. I still hear some bad sound and also the volume becomes low to hear which is not good. Is there any effect or other way to reduce distortion?

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as my knowledge over that problem extends.  Good luck :)